# latexmk and glossaries

Tags: glossaries, latexmk

I am having trouble getting `\printglossary` to work, when using `latexmk`.

I have this minimal working example `glossary.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{apple}{name={apple},description={a yellow fruit}}
\newglossaryentry{pear}{name={pear},description={a green fruit}}
\newacronym{kcal}{kcal}{kilo calorie}
\newacronym{kJ}{kJ}{kilo Joule}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Fruit section}
\Gls{apple} or \gls{apple} or \glspl{apple}. Also \gls{pear}. How many \glspl{kcal} and \glspl{kJ}?

%\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
%\printglossary

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]
\printglossary[title=Nomenclature]

\end{document}
```

It works neatly, when I compile with `pdflatex`:

```
rm *.glo *.gls
pdflatex glossary
makeglossaries glossary
pdflatex glossary
open glossary.pdf &
```

Why are the glossaries not printed, when using `latexmk`?

```
rm *.glo *.gls
latexmk -pdf glossary
makeglossaries glossary
latexmk -pdf glossary
open glossary.pdf &
```

If I remember correctly I switched from `pdflatex` to `latexmk`, because the former didn't work well with `biblatex`. Anyway, I really want it to work for the latter.

Comment: OK, so I got it to work with my real example. I have no clue why this is, but this jobname without a punctuation will work `latexmk -pdf -jobname=foo_bar glossary`, whereas this jobname with a punctuation will fail `latexmk -pdf -jobname=foo.bar glossary`